# Virtual hosts with port 80 & 443 not working

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl, virtualhost, https, port-443

I can't figure out why I can't connect to my VPS.

httpd.conf: i added:

```
Listen 80
listen 443

NameVirtualHost *:80
NameVirtualHost *:443

 <VirtualHost *:80>
    SSLEngine off
    ServerAdmin webmaster@example.com
    DocumentRoot somepath
    ServerName somedomain
    ErrorLog something
    CustomLog something common
 </VirtualHost>

 <VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@example.com
    DocumentRoot somepath
    ServerName somedomain
    ErrorLog something
    CustomLog something common

    SSLEngine on
    SSLProtocol -all +SSLv2
    SSLCipherSuite SSLv2:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:+LOW:+EXP
    SSLCertificateFile something
    SSLCertificateKeyFile something
    SSLCertificateChainFile something
    SSLCertificateChainFile something
 </VirtualHost>
```

mod_ssl is installed

There seem to be no syntax errors:

```
/usr/sbin/httpd -t
Syntax OK
```

The DocumentRoot path is right, because it worked when I just used port 80/ had not added anything to try to make port 443 work.

Yet it's not working (neither with http:// nor https://) ... Did I overlook something?

Comment: What is not working?

Comment: I can't access the server through the domain name (the browser tells me it can't access the server)

Comment: Have you checked that the domain name exists correctly in DNS? Have you checked with `netstat -lnp` that Apache is listening to ports 443 / 40?

Comment: What is the exact error message that the browser gives you ?

Comment: it probably gives you a warning when you restart httpd/apache service, no? I believe the warning will tell you, you cannot have both `443` and `80` assigned to virtual hosts. That warning/error is correct. Listen to it.

Comment: Is there any error in your error log file ?